# Does "indent" term using only for horizontal gap?

Tags: css, terminology

Is it correct to say "(vertical) indent before unordered list"?
Or "indent" term using only for horizontal spacing?

Comment: do you mean `margin-bottom`? I don't think there's anything called as vertical indent.

Comment: I believe If the writing direction is vertical e.g. `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`. The "indent"(`text-indent`) means vertical gap for the first line of the paragraph.

Comment: @Prajwal, Thank you for the comment. I mean the vertical space between two block. How it could be achieved is other matter - it could be margin-bottom for first block, margin-top of second blocks, save for paddings and transparent borders. Common term required for all these cases.

Comment: The question about terminology always downvoted. Anyone can tell why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indent` as a CSS property describes the space before the **content horizontally** floating on the left as shown in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

If you would like to achieve s.th. similar vertically, you have to use `padding`, `margin` or some `flexbox` logic whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It means I should not use the term indent for vertical gaps...